# Why is my Emacs widget's :notify never called?

Tags: events, emacs, widget, elisp

I have the following elisp:

```
(require 'widget)

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'wid-edit))

(defun testit ()
  (interactive)

  (switch-to-buffer "*Widget Test*")

  (widget-insert "Test field: ")
  (widget-create 'editable-field
         :size 25
         :notify (lambda (widget &rest ignore)
               (message (widget-value widget))))

  (use-local-map widget-keymap)
  (widget-setup))
```

It creates a text widget in a new Emacs buffer.  I intend it to show the value of the widget in the minibuffer on each change, but it doesn't seem ever to call the :notify function.  Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it didn't work because I had unknowingly messed up widget.el and needed to reload the package.  Restarting Emacs did the trick.

Comment: You might want to accept your own answer, so that the question does no longer appear to be open.

Comment: @Thomas: I can't for 2 days after I post it --- but Stack Overflow doesn't make that obvious to anyone but me.

Comment: Ah, right, I remember running into a similar problem once. Thanks for being considerate, though.

Comment: I'm experiencing this aswell, are you positive this is the only fix? I never even opened the library/source.

Comment: @ldionmarcil --- I'm not at all sure that's the only fix, but it fixed it, and I've never had it happen again, so I never tried anything else.